# Why does the required resulting string length for sprintf("%.8190f", .Machine$double.xmax) or sprintf("%.8190f", (2-2^(-52))*2^1023) equal to 8500?

Tags: r, floating-point, double, limit, notation

In normalized double precision representation, thinking "1." of "1.f" in fractional part leads us to reduce `sprintf` maximal from 8192 to 8190.

Now;

```
identical(.Machine$double.xmax, (2-2^(-52))*2^1023) # TRUE

sprintf("%.8190f", .Machine$double.xmax)
# Error in sprintf("%.8190f", .Machine$double.xmax) : required resulting string length 8500 is greater than maximal 8192

sprintf("%.8190f", (2-2^(-52))*2^1023)
# Error in sprintf("%.8190f", (2 - 2^(-52)) * 2^1023) : required resulting string length 8500 is greater than maximal 8192

sprintf("%.8190f", .Machine$double.xmax- 10^308)
# Error in sprintf("%.8190f", .Machine$double.xmax - 10^308) : required resulting string length 8499 is greater than maximal 8192

sprintf("%.7882f", -.Machine$double.xmax) 
# Error in sprintf("%.7882f", -.Machine$double.xmax) : required resulting string length 8193 is greater than maximal 8192
sprintf("%.7881f", -.Machine$double.xmax) # Seamlessly shows the result.
```

(2-2^(-52) ) 2^1023  ≈ 1,797693 x 10^308. So, where does this 8500 in 
 `sprintf` output materialize from?

Also, the Value of `sprintf` is: *A character vector of length that of the longest input. If any element of fmt or any character argument is declared as UTF-8, the element of the result will be in UTF-8 and have the encoding declared as UTF-8. Otherwise it will be in the current locale's encoding.*

So, `sprintf` seems **not** to give the 64-bit double precesion floating point representation of a numeric value?

Comment: Try, `sprintf("%.8190f",9.68595); nchar(sprintf("%.8190f",9.68595))` So, does 8192 not contain the "X digits exponent of 2base" equivalent of "309 digits exponent of 10base"?

Comment: “X digits exponent of 2base” is not a meaningful phrase. `nchar(sprintf("%.8190f",9.68595))` produces 8192 because there is one digit before the decimal point, one decimal point, and 8190 digits after the decimal point. If you change the “9” to 90”, it would require 8193 characters.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Very helpful comment indeed, especially, 9->90 8193 part. I tried it and resulted in just as you said.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ”`%.`*n*`f`” format produces a negative sign if needed, the integer decimal digits of the number being printed, a period, and as many decimal digits as specified by *n*. Thus, for the greatest representable finite value around 1.797693•10<sup>308</sup>, `%.8190f` would produce 309 digits, one decimal point, and 8,190 zeros after the decimal point, totaling 8,500 characters.

As confirmation, observe the result of `nchar(sprintf("%.100f", .Machine$double.xmax))` is 410, for 309 digits, one decimal point, and 100 zeros after the decimal point.

Comment: Thanks a lot Eric! You really observed very well what is going on.